# Verification of a proof by cardinality of the existence of irrationals

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

I was asked to proof, by cardinality, that there are irrationals. Couldn't find much that was explicitly using as nuclear part of the argument the cardinality of the sets. I guess the closest I've find was proofs of the uncountability of irrationals, but not of the existence of them. Anyway, I'm willing to put the proof I came to at scrutiny.

**Prop.:** There are irrational real numbers.

**Proof:**

The cardinality of $\mathbb R$ is strictly greater than that of $\mathbb N$ (so than that of $\mathbb Q$). Take $\mathbb R\setminus\mathbb Q$. Since $\mathbb Q$ is countable, then $\mathbb R\setminus\mathbb Q$ must be uncountable, and, therefore, there must be non-rationals numbers that form a proper subset of $\mathbb R$ that is uncountable. We have then to show that $|\mathbb R\setminus\mathbb Q|$ > $|\mathbb Q|$.

Suppose, by contradiction, that it is not the case. Then $|\mathbb R\setminus\mathbb Q|$ ≤ $|\mathbb Q|$. Since any infinite proper subset of $\mathbb N$ has cardinality equals $|\mathbb N|$, it implies that $|\mathbb R\setminus\mathbb Q|$ = $|\mathbb Q| = |\mathbb N|$. So there must be a bijection between $\mathbb N$ and $\mathbb R\setminus\mathbb Q$. Now taking $Q$, the set of rationals in (0, 1) (which has cardinality $|\mathbb N|$, make $f(n)$ = $1/n$, $n ≥ 0$) and (0, 1), construct $R$ = $(0, 1)$/$Q$. Then $|R|$ must be ≤ $|\mathbb R\setminus\mathbb Q|$ (can I claim that without proving it?). Now take $L$, the indexed list of all strings of $R$. Since $\mathbb R\setminus\mathbb Q$ is supposed to be countable, and so must be $R$, this list must contain all numbers (represented as strings) of $R$. Each string is of the form: $s_i = a_1a_2...a_j...$; $i≥0, j≥1$. Referring to $a_j$ as $s_i[j]$ we can make a string $s$ as follows:

$s[1] ≠ s_0[1]; s[2] ≠ s_1[2];$ and, in general, $s[j] ≠ s_{j-1}[j]$.

Note that $s$ is not in $L$, but is in $R$ (is it clear that $s$ stands for a non-rational number?). Therefore there is not enumeration for $R$. Consequently, since $|R|$ ≤ $|\mathbb R\setminus\mathbb Q|$, there is not for the latter also. So $|\mathbb R\setminus\mathbb Q|$ > $|\mathbb Q|$. Ergo there must be non-rational numbers that form an uncountable proper subset of $\mathbb R$.

Comment: How did you prove that the reals were uncountable?

Comment: Well it was the question before that in the problem's list I'm solving, so I just assumed that. But I don't think I would have to prove that, would I?

Comment: Well, yes. If you don't know (i.e.: haven't proved or seen proof) that the reals are uncountable, how can you use that as a fact? Of course, if your professor says you can take that for granted, then it's fine.

Comment: If you already proved that the reals are uncountable, you don't have to do it all over again. I was just curious what method you'd used/seen to prove that the reals are uncountable.

Comment: I used Cantor's diagonal argument. It was quite similar to this proof, only instead of using this set I called $R$, I used the interval $(0, 1)$.

Comment: Excellent! In that case, you should be basically set to go! Just follow Noah's hints.

Answer (score 5):

This is much more complicated than necessary. You know $\mathbb{Q}$ is countable, and $\mathbb{Q}\subseteq\mathbb{R}$. So if there were no irrationals - that is, if $\mathbb{R}=\mathbb{Q}$ - what can you say about the cardinality of $\mathbb{R}$? Does this contradict anything you know?

Comment: You're right. What I wrongly thought was that just the fact that $|\mathbb R|$ ≥ $|\mathbb Q|$ would not necessarily imply the existence of irrationals.  But indeed just the fact that there is something (which $|\mathbb R|$ ≥ $|\mathbb Q|$ guarantees) between the reals and the rationals, that is not rational, implies that there are irrationals.

Comment: @izzorts In fact you know something stronger: $\lvert \Bbb N \rvert < \lvert \Bbb R \rvert$.

Comment: @izzorts I think you mean "$>$", not "$\ge$", in your comment.

Comment: Indeed, I meant '>'. Otherwise it wouldn't imply securely the existence of something between the rationals and the reals.